# How to make s:radio ordered list?

Tags: css, struts2, struts, struts2-jquery

I am working in Struts2.0 as a fresher.

My code.

```
<s:radio list="{'EOD1','EOD2','JCR_ELECT'}" name="searchCriteria" cssStyle="margin-left: 5px;"/>
```

This code generates a list but is not ordered.
This is printed as EOD1 EOD2 JCR_ELECT
But I want to printed this radio button like 
EOD1 
EOD2 
JCR_ELECT

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use Struts 2.0, use Struts 2.3.16.3, due to a lot of reasons, including security, features and performances

Answer (score 0):

Change the display of those radio buttons to `block`:

```
input[type="radio"][name="searchCriteria"]{
  display:block;
}
```